# Find $x$ that minimizes $\max_{1 \leq i \leq 3} f_i(x)$

Tags: calculus, optimization

My question is:

> For $0 < a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3$ fixed, **find $x>0$ that minimizes** 
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x) = \max_{1\leq i \leq 3} f_i(x).
> \end{align*}
>   where
>   \begin{align*}
> f_i(x) =  \left(\frac{a_i - x}{a_i + x}\right)^2
> \end{align*}

I do not know how to start. Any idea, reference is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: @epimorphic Yes, from trying different examples, I think the answer could be $x^* = \sqrt{a_1 a_3}$. I am trying to see this by understanding the form of $g$: studying the relative position of the $f_i$, finding the points where $g$ is not differentiable, etc. (As a side note, one can compute that $f_1(x^*) = \left( \frac{\sqrt{a_1} - \sqrt{a_3}}{\sqrt{a_1} - \sqrt{a_3}}\right)^2 = f_3(x^*)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution to my question.

> Answer: the minimizer is $x = \sqrt{a_1 a_3}$.

Let $0 < \underline{a} < \overline{a}$ be fixed. We study the relative position of $f_{\underline{a}}$ and $f_{\overline{a}}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f_{\underline{a}}(x) = \left(\frac{\underline{a} - x}{\underline{a} + x}\right)^2, \qquad 
f_{\overline{a}}(x) = \left(\frac{\overline{a} - x}{\overline{a} + x}\right)^2
\end{align*}
for $x>0$. Let $h$ be defined by $h = f_{\underline{a}} - f_{\overline{a}}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
h(x) &= \frac{(\underline{a}-x)^2(\overline{a} + x)^2 - (\overline{a} - x)^2(\underline{a}+x)^2}{(\underline{a}+x)^2(\overline{a}+x)^2}\\
&= \frac{\big[(\underline{a}-x)(\overline{a} + x) - (\overline{a} - x)(\underline{a}+x)\big]\big[(\underline{a}-x)(\overline{a} + x) + (\overline{a} - x)(\underline{a}+x)\big]}{(\underline{a}+x)^2(\overline{a}+x)^2}\\
&= \frac{4 x (\overline{a} - \underline{a})(x^2 - \underline{a}\overline{a})}{(\underline{a}+x)^2(\overline{a}+x)^2}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f_{\underline{a}} < f_{\overline{a}}$ for $x \in (0, \sqrt{\underline{a}\overline{a}})$, $f_{\underline{a}} = f_{\overline{a}}$ for $x = \sqrt{\underline{a}\overline{a}}$, and $f_{\underline{a}} > f_{\overline{a}}$ for $x \in (\sqrt{\underline{a}\overline{a}}, +\infty)$. Since $0 < a_1 < a_2 < a_3$, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
&f_1 \leq f_2 \quad \text{if} \quad x \leq \sqrt{a_1 a_2}, \quad\text{otherwise} \quad f_1>f_2,\\
&f_1 \leq f_3 \quad \text{if} \quad x \leq \sqrt{a_1 a_3}, \quad\text{otherwise} \quad f_1>f_3, \\
&f_2 \leq f_3 \quad \text{if} \quad x \leq \sqrt{a_2 a_3}, \quad\text{otherwise} \quad f_2 > f_3.
\end{align*}
Consequently, the maximum is given by
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \begin{cases}
f_3(x) & \text{if }x \leq \sqrt{a_1 a_3}\\
f_1(x) & \text{if }x > \sqrt{a_1 a_3}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, for $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, 
\begin{align*}
f_i'(x) = \frac{4 a_i (x- a_i)}{(a_i+x)^3}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f_i$ is decreasing on $(0, a_i]$, and increasing on $(a_i, + \infty)$. This implies that $f_3$ is decreasing on $(0, \sqrt{a_1 a_3}]$, and $f_1$ is increasing on $(\sqrt{a_1a_3}, + \infty)$. Hence, $g(x)$ is the smallest for $x = \sqrt{a_1 a_3}$.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was going to suggest, to find where $g = f_i$ for each $i$, because they don't just switch around randomly 

Comment: A few minor errors I think: (1) the final expression for $h(x)$ should have a factor of $x$ in the numerator (note that numerator should have degree 4); (2) in the expression for $f'_i(x)$ the exponent should be $3$ instead (note by dimensional analysis the denominator should be one degree higher than the numerator).

Comment: @epimorphic Thank you for the feedback and for pointing out the errors (I agree with both errors), I edited to correct them.

Comment: $f_i’$ is still off by a factor of 2. Should be 4 instead of 2 in the numerator.

Comment: @Rob Pratt Indeed, thank you. I edited to correct that.

Answer (score -1):

You can introduce a new variable $z$ and minimize $z$ subject to $$z \ge \left(\frac{a_i-x}{a_i+x}\right)^2$$ for all $i$.  This reformulation avoids the nondifferentiable $\max$ function.  Maybe you can try the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this reformulation clarifies much of anything at all. Specifically addressing Lagrange multipliers: The method exploits the insight that at sufficiently smooth extrema, the constraints should be tangent to the contours of the objective function. If we try to introduce a new variable in a 1D problem such as here, the level sets are just $z=k$, so we'd be looking for solutions of $f'_i(x) = 0$... which is exactly what you would first try in 1D calculus, but with an unnecessary detour. And it doesn't get us to the answer in this case.

Comment: Also, inequalities don't work as constraints – they specify regions with the same dimension as the ambient space, and regions can't be tangent to contours in the sense of Lagrange multipliers as you're always free to move perpendicular to contours within the constraint.